# Query Modified Date

Tags: csom, caml-query

I found tons of samples with query for modified. But following keeps giving an exception that the query limit was to large (I gues it is the threshold limit).

```
var query = 
         $@"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
             <Query>
                <Where>
                 <Lt>                  
                     <FieldRef Name = 'Modified' /> 
                     <Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='1'/></Value>
                 </Lt>
             </Where>
             </Query>
             <ViewFields></ViewFields>
             <RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>1000</RowLimit>
         </View>";
```

Kind of wierd when following works:

```
var query = 
        $@"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
            <Query>
               <Where>
                <Lt>
                    <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                    <Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>
                </Lt>
            </Where>
            </Query>
            <ViewFields></ViewFields>
            <RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>1000</RowLimit>
        </View>";
```

Complete code:

```
var query = 
$@"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
    <Query>
        <Where>
        <Lt>
            <FieldRef Name='ID' />
            <Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>
        </Lt>
    </Where>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields></ViewFields>
    <RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>1000</RowLimit>
</View>";

ListItemCollectionPosition position = null;
var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = query; 
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

do
{
    using (var clonedCtx = ctx.Clone(ctx.Url))
    {
        List listWithClonedContext = clonedCtx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(list.Title);
        clonedCtx.Load(listWithClonedContext);
        clonedCtx.ExecuteQueryWithIncrementalRetry(3, logger);

        ListItemCollection listItems = null;
        camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
        listItems = listWithClonedContext.GetItems(camlQuery);

        clonedCtx.Load(listItems);
        clonedCtx.ExecuteQueryWithIncrementalRetry(3, logger);        

        itemsResult.AddRange(listItems);       
        position = listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;   
    }
}
while (position != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need to use a CAML query but I was able to get the modified date with the following CSOM code in Powershell:

```
$ItemId = 1
$FieldName = "Modified"
$ListName = "MyListName"

$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$ListItem = $List.GetItemById($ItemId)
$Context.Load($ListItem)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$Value = $ListItem.FieldValues.$FieldName
```

$Value has the date Modified value.

You could loop through for each item number.

Hope this helps.